# Where does the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}z^n$ converge?

Tags: solution-verification, power-series, pointwise-convergence

$z \in \mathbb C$ here.

It's a power series with coefficints $c_n := \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$, hence part of the work is the computation of the convergence radius. Here it is: $$ \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} = \frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \to \frac14 \quad \text{as } n \to +\infty$$ That is, the radius is $4$ and the series converges for $\lvert z \rvert < 4$.

What if $\lvert z \rvert = 4$? If $z = 4$, then the series does not converge. This is done by using the Stirling formula [it is suggested me to do so]: the terms are $$ c_n 4^n \sim \frac{2 \pi n \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 \pi 2 n} \left( \frac{2n}{e} \right)^{2n}} 4^n = \sqrt{\pi n} \quad \text{as } n \to +\infty$$ Consequently, the series *does not* converge for $z = 4$.

But what if $\lvert z \rvert = 4$ and $z \ne 4$? The sequence of the $c_n$'s is decreasing and convergent to $0$, hence we can apply the Dirichlet test, to say that in this case converges.

Is the solution right?

Comment: It's the behaviour of $|c_nz^n|$, not $c_n$, that matters. Surely $|c_nz^n|=c_n4^n\sim\sqrt{n\pi}$ tells us by the term test the series diverges whenever $|z|=4$.

Comment: *"hence we can apply the Dirichlet test [...] Is the solution right?"* Before asking, please review the hypothesis of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: Using the notation of the wiki article, $a_n := c_n$ and $b_n := z^n$. Here the partial sums of the $b_n$'s are all bounded by $\frac{2}{\lvert 1-z \rvert}$, aren't they?

Comment: They are clearly unbounded (remember that $|z|=4$).